# Dirac Equation Dimensionality

Tags: dirac-equation, dirac-matrices

In Griffith's Introduction to Elementary Particles, the Dirac equation is given during its derivation as (Equation 7.19):

$$
\gamma ^ \mu p_\mu - mc = 0
$$

However, the dimensions don't seem to make sense, since each element of $\gamma$ 
 (that is, each $\gamma^\mu$) is a 4x4 matrix and each element of $p$ is a number. How does this equation make sense?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is an implied 4x4 identity matrix on the $mc$ term.